# Date change when converting from XMLGregorianCalendar to Calendar

Tags: java, datetime, casting

When testing out a web service that maps datetime types between systems, I noticed that sending any date before the Gregorian calendar start time resulted in a loss of accuracy when casting to the final type, with the end result always slightly ahead in time in the range of a few days.

I narrowed down the problem to the exact line, but I still can't figure out *why* it's being cast like so, from the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html) it states that the Julian calendar is used for datetimes before the Gregorian calendar start: October 15, 1582.

The problem line is at the cast from `XMLGregorianCalendar` to `GregorianCalendar`, line 78: `calendarDate = argCal.toGregorianCalendar();`
When the time is taken from `calendarDate` on line 86: `cal.setTime(calendarDate.getTime());` The time comes back 2 days ahead of what it should be, Jan. 03 instead of Jan. 01, as you'll see from the output in the program below.

Here's a sample program I made to show the casting process end to end:

```
import java.sql.Date;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

import javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeFactory;
import javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar;



public class TestDateConversions {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        TestDateConversions testDates = new TestDateConversions();
        try
        {
            XMLGregorianCalendar testDate1 = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar();
            testDate1.setYear(0001);
            testDate1.setMonth(01);
            testDate1.setDay(01);
            System.out.println("Start date: "+testDate1.toString() +"\n**********************");

            testDates.setXMLGregorianCalendar(testDate1);
            System.out.println("\nNull given \n"+ "**********");
            testDates.setXMLGregorianCalendar(null);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }


    public void setXMLGregorianCalendar(XMLGregorianCalendar argCal)
    {
        GregorianCalendar calendarDate;
        if (argCal != null)
        {
            calendarDate = argCal.toGregorianCalendar();
            System.out.println("XMLGregorianCalendar time: " + argCal.getHour() + ":"+argCal.getMinute()+":"+argCal.getSecond());
            System.out.println("XMLGregorianCalendar time(ms): "+argCal.getMillisecond());
            System.out.println("XMLGregorianCalendar -> GregorianCalendar: "+calendarDate.get(GregorianCalendar.YEAR) + "-"+(calendarDate.get(GregorianCalendar.MONTH)+1) + "-"+calendarDate.get(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
            System.out.println("!!!!PROBLEM AREA!!!!");
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            System.out.println("-- New Calendar instance: "+cal.get(Calendar.YEAR) + "-"+(cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1)+"-"+cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
            System.out.println("-- Calling Calendar.setTime(GregorianCalendar.getTime())");
            cal.setTime(calendarDate.getTime());
            System.out.println("-- calendarDate.getTime() = " + calendarDate.getTime() + " <-- time is incorrect");
            System.out.println("-- Calendar with time set from GregorianCalendar: "+cal.get(Calendar.YEAR) + "-"+(cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1)+"-"+cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + " <-- day is increased here");
            setCalendar(cal);
        }
        else 
        {
            setCalendar(null);
        }
    }

    public void setCalendar(Calendar argCal)
    {
        if (argCal != null)
        {
            Date date = new Date(argCal.getTimeInMillis());
            System.out.println("Calendar to Date: "+date);
            setDate(date);
        }
        else
        {
            setDate(null);
        }

    }

    public void setDate(Date argDate)
    {
        try
        {
            if (argDate == null)
            {
                Calendar cal  = new GregorianCalendar(1,0,1);
                Date nullDate = new Date(cal.getTimeInMillis());
                System.out.println("Null Calendar created: "+cal.get(Calendar.YEAR) + "-"+(cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1)+"-"+cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
                System.out.println("Null Date created: "+nullDate);
            }
            else 
            {
                System.out.println("Final date type: "+argDate);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception  ex)
        {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: FWIW: The Julian calendar did not go away instantly in 1582. Maybe this software really does that (a bad idea IMO), but underlying system code may not not. Please give us an exact example (old date, expected date, result date).

Comment: @jimmcnamara I'm not saying anything went away, I just pointed out that any date *before* the Gregorian time is being changed. My exact example is pretty obvious there in the program code, the date `0001-01-01` is being changed to `0001-01-03`, and it should not be.

Comment: Okay - to be honest this looks like a problem in the library.  As a hypothesis let's say it is trying the Proleptic Calendar.  It is still off from Julian by the wrong amount.  You are completely correct. http://calendars.wikia.com/wiki/Proleptic_Gregorian_calendar --

Comment: @jimmcnamara Thanks Jim. If that's the case, then I'm honestly not too sure of where to go from here, I guess I could report it.

Comment: There might be something bad with time zones. On one project when we converted `Date => LocalDate => Date` (JodaTime in the middle) we got a result which was 15 minutes off the original date. The thing was that TZ data of Java was older than what Joda had (missing 15min shift declared in 1891). These kind of things can happen if you are working with a date and mixing timestamp representation and calendar field representation. Back then we have solved our problem with Joda through a dedicated method for this purpose -> http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html .

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Excerpt from [`XMLGregorianCalendar.toGregorianCalendar()` JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/datatype/XMLGregorianCalendar.html#toGregorianCalendar%28%29) on how they create the `GregorianCalendar` instance:

> Obtain a pure Gregorian Calendar by invoking GregorianCalendar.setGregorianChange( new Date(Long.MIN_VALUE)).

This means, that the created calendar will be proleptic and won't switch to Julian calendar as it does by default for old dates. Then the problem is here:

- `argCal.toGregorianCalendar()` - converting from *XMLGregorianCalendar* to *GregorianCalendar* **using field representation** (Julian system is not used - see above)
- `cal.setTime(calendarDate.getTime());`

  - this is actually converting field representation to a **timestamp representation** and initializing a new calendar with this timestamp
  - the new calendar is using Julian system to represent the date as it is older than 1582

There are few ways how to solve this:

- use JodaTime and [`LocalDate#fromCalendarFiels`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html#fromCalendarFields%28java.util.Calendar%29) if you are interested only in the date
- <del>convert calendars using field access and not the `#getTime` method</del>
- force the gregorian calendar to use proleptic system (in the same way as *XMLGregorianCalendar* is doing it)

---

**UPDATE** Please note that Java Date and Calendar APIs are not so well designed and can be (and are) sometimes pretty confusing. This is also why Java 8 contains completely reworked date-time library [JSR-310](https://java.net/projects/jsr-310) (based on JodaTime by the way).

Now, you have to realize, that you can store and work with a specific **instant** (calendar independent keyword) via two very different approaches:

- storing an offset (e.g. in milliseconds) from a well defined *instant* called epoch (e.g. [unix epoch 1970-01-01](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time))
- storing date by its calendar fields (e.g. 1st of January 1970)

The first approach is what is being used under the hood in `java.util.Date`. However this representation is usually non-human friendly. Humans work with calendar dates, not timestamps. Converting timestamps to date fields is where Calendar steps in. Also that is where the funny part starts... if you want to represent date by its fields, you need to realize that there are always multiple ways how to do that. Some nation can decide to use lunar months, others may say that the year 0 was just 10 years ago. And gregorian calendar is just one way of converting actual instant to actual date fields.

A bit on *XMLGregorianCalendar* vs *GregorianCalendar*:

- XML specification explicitly says that the human-readable date is a *gregorian calendar* date
- Java's *GregorianCalendar* contains this *"magic"*, which switches to Julian system under the hood, if the instant is older than a defined switch-over date
- that is why *XMLGregorianCalendar* modifies *GregorianCalendar* during its initialization to disable this magic switch (see the excerpt from JavaDoc above)

Now the interesting part:

If the Julian switch won't be disabled, *GregorianCalendar* would assume that the calendar fields are from Julian system and it will shift them by 3 days. You thought that the date has been shifted by 3 days and something must've went wrong, right? **No, the date was actually all the time correct** and it contained correct timestamp under the hood! Only the calendar had presented you Julian fields instead of Gregorian fields. And this is pretty confusing I would say :) [JSR-310 laughing in the background].

So if you want to work with pure gregorian calendar (i.e. to use so called *proleptic gregorian* for old dates), you need to initialize calendar like this:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
((GregorianCalendar) calendar).setGregorianChange(new Date(Long.MIN_VALUE));
```

You might say: `calendar.getTime()` is still giving me incorrect date. Well, that is because `java.util.Date.toString()` (called by `System.out.println`) is using the default `Calendar`, which will switch to Julian system for older dates. Confused? Maybe angry (I know I am :))?

---

**UPDATE 2**

```
// Get XML gregorian calendar
XMLGregorianCalendar xmlCalendar = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar();
xmlCalendar.setYear(1); // Watch for octal number representations (you had there 0001)
xmlCalendar.setMonth(1);
xmlCalendar.setDay(1);

// Convert to Calendar as it is easier to work with it
Calendar calendar = xmlCalendar.toGregorianCalendar(); // Proleptic for old dates

// Convert to default calendar (will misinterpret proleptic for Julian, but it is a workaround)
Calendar result = Calendar.getInstance();
result.setTimeZone(calendar.getTimeZone());
result.set(Calendar.YEAR, calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR));
result.set(Calendar.MONTH, calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH));
result.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
result.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
result.set(Calendar.MINUTE, calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
result.set(Calendar.SECOND, calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND));
result.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, calendar.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND));

System.out.println(result.getTime());
```

Disclamer: **this code is wrong** (the result instant is not the same as the one in the XML file), but OP understands the problem and its consequences (see the discussion under this answer).

Comment: Thanks Pavel. I unfortunately can't use Joda in this situation, can you show bullets 2 and 3 please?

Comment: I've updated the answer with some background information on Date and Calendar interactions. Also I have deleted the second bullet as it was not correct advice and would lead you into more problems.

Comment: That last part just made it more confusing. How would I apply your solution to what I have? In other words where would I incorporate `((GregorianCalendar) calendar).setGregorianChange(new Date(Long.MIN_VALUE));` in my `setXMLGregorianCalendar` method and use it to get the date from the `GregorianCalendar` variable?

Comment: You should call this method every time you create or obtain new Calendar instance.

Comment: Also the point I was trying to make was that the date **was never incorrect**... it was just displayed in Julian system. Conversion to proleptic Gregorian can be made just before you display it to user if needed. But there is nothing wrong if you force every calendar in your application to be proleptic. However `Date#toString` will probably always switch to Julian and display "incorrect" value.

Comment: I have to send a type of Date so I can't convert it back to Gregorian, the methods shown in my code are the ones I have to use. So, can you either 1) Show how to force the calendars to be proleptic or 2) Show how to properly "call this method every time you create  or obtain new Calendar instance" as what you provided does not resolve my issue when used in the example I provided.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50798/discussion-between-pavel-horal-and-jwiley)

Comment: @JWiley I've added the wanted example of "incorrect" calendar conversion. Now that I am sure you understand the consequences I am no longer ashamed for that :).

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though you are accidentally converting from the Gregorian Calendar to the Julian Calendar. The day that the (extrapolated or *proleptic*) Gregorian Calendar refers to as 0001-01-01 is, indeed, 0001-01-03 in the Julian Calendar. If you change your date to 1001-01-01, you will find that your end result is 1000-12-26. This is consistent with date conversions from Gregorian to Julian, as the offset changes over time. It was actually positive before the 4th century, but has been negative (and getting more negative over time) since then.

The instance of `XMLGregorianCalendar` I get is actually a `com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendarImpl` and the `toGregorianCalendar()` method includes these lines:

```
    result = new GregorianCalendar(tz, locale);
    result.clear();
    result.setGregorianChange(PURE_GREGORIAN_CHANGE);
```

This makes the calendar an purely proleptic GregorianCalendar, so that dates before 1583 are still converted from the epoch time (milliseconds since 1970) by the Gregorian algorithm. Which means the problem is probably in `GregorianCalendar`...

Which is indeed the case. Try this sample program and you'll see:

```
public static void main(String...args) {
    GregorianCalendar gcal = new GregorianCalendar();
    gcal.clear();
    gcal.setGregorianChange(new Date(Long.MIN_VALUE));
    gcal.set(Calendar.YEAR, 1);  // or any other year before 1582
    gcal.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.JANUARY);
    gcal.set(Calendar.DATE, 1);

    Date d = gcal.getTime();
    System.out.println(d);
}
```

The field values going in are interpreted as Gregorian due to the value of `getGregorianChange()`... but coming out (converting from epoch milliseconds) that field seems to be disobeyed. The `Date` that comes out of `getTime()` has no concept of what the Gregorian changeover value was. This may or may not be a bug, but it's certainly unexpected behaviour.