# Date changed during convert XMLGregorianCalendar to GregorianCalendar

Tags: java

I am struggling with the below date convert.

**Original Date**: Jan 2 0001 18:00 PM GMT-5:00.

**Expected Date**: Jan 3 0001 7:00 AM GMT+8:00.
**Actual Date**: Jan 5 0001 7:00 AM GMT+8:00.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    XMLGregorianCalendar xmlC;
    try {
        xmlC = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar();
        xmlC.setYear(1);
        xmlC.setMonth(1);
        xmlC.setDay(2); // It is Jan 2!!
        xmlC.setHour(18);
        xmlC.setMinute(0);
        xmlC.setSecond(0);
        xmlC.setMillisecond(0);
        xmlC.setTimezone(-300);
        GregorianCalendar gC = xmlC.toGregorianCalendar();
        System.out.println(gC.getTime()); // Actual output: Wed Jan 05 07:00:00 CST 1
    } catch (DatatypeConfigurationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

May you please help me on this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16321193/date-change-when-converting-from-xmlgregoriancalendar-to-calendar

Comment: BTW, why are you using a year value of `0001`?

Answer (score 5):

As explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16321193/date-change-when-converting-from-xmlgregoriancalendar-to-calendar), your calendar is being shifted because you have specified your year as `1`, meaning that this falls out of the `GregorianCalendar` and into the Julian Calendar, which `XMLGregorianCalendar` does not support.

Simply use `xmlC.setYear(2016);` to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

try this into your code

```
XMLGregorianCalendar xmlC;
Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
try {
    xmlC = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar();
    xmlC.setYear(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR));
    ....
```